# AmCharts v4 AmMap change language

Tags: amcharts

I would like to change the language of a ammap (V4).

Therefore I followed the example which is provided here (but it is for V3): http://jsfiddle.net/tDqs2/25/

Here first the language get loaded via a script tag.

```
<script src="http://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/3/lang-maps/de.js">
```

Now if I follow the instructions I don't see any map.
Here is my codepen:
https://codepen.io/ms92o/pen/mjMpZy

that line does not work:

```
chart.language = 'de';
```

Looking at the API for language I do find a language property:
https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/mapchart/

But how do I set the language?
The language constructor does not need any parameters

```
let language = new am4core.Language();
// How to change that language to 'DE'.
```

Comment: Just to let you know, as far as I can tell from the distributed source code there is currently no translation for german in AmChart v4 (https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/tree/master/dist/script/lang). Even if you get the language to change, you'd still need to manually translate every string.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I understand that, but what is the process of changing the language, even if I have to create the File myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A German translation was added earlier this month](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4-lang/commit/6e1efc9348b0bc45b93dfdeb8d6deda34f76fcda).

You can find other currently available translations here: https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4-lang/tree/master/src

To change the language to say, German, we have to include the translation first as it isn't [one of the bundled locales](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/locales/#Bundled_locales):

```
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/lang/de_DE.js"></script>
```

Then to change the language, each chart has a language property, we update its locale property, i.e. `chart.language.locale`, to the translation of choice:

```
chart.language.locale = am4lang_de_DE;
```

(Please note, updating the chart's language dynamically is not yet supported in v4. If it's something you're interested in, please subscribe to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/271) to keep posted.)

Here's a simple chart demo in English:
https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/ZRaWJQ

Same demo in German via above code: https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/4d968a6f292fca2dc59d5e75b0389e0e/

If you would like to roll your own translation or contribute to an existing one, check out the [Creating Translations guide](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/creating-translations/).